# Self complete a field under conditions on Odoo v8 new api

Tags: python, odoo-8

I developed a module for odoo 8 where I place one field who received a art of code of 8 characters and a function completed the field with a letter.

This is the field:

```
<field name="Nif" data-inputmask="'mask': '99999999-a'"/>
```

And this is the code in python:

```
@api.onchange('Nif')
def letraDNI(self):
    numero = self.Nif
    intnumero = int(numero[:7])
    diccionario = {'0': "T", '1': "R", '2': "W", '3': "A", '4': "G", '5': "M", '6': "Y", '7': "F", '8': "P", '9': "D", '10': "X",'11': "B", '12': "N", '13': "J", '14': "Z", '15': "S", '16': "Q", '17': "V", '18': "H", '19': "L",'20': "C", '21': "K", '22': "E"}
    resto = intnumero % 23
    letra = diccionario.get(resto)
```

But where you try proceed the program say:

```
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/addons/admision/models.py", line 60, in letraDNI
   self.Nif = str(numero + letra)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Any solution?

Comment: wrongly add the field level attribute data-inputmask on field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resto` is a number, while the keys in `diccionario` are strings, hence the key is not found, and `diccionario.get(resto)` returns `None`. Then attempting to add `Unicode` type with `None` causes the exception.

Try:

```
letra = diccionario.get(str(resto))
```

or change the dictionary keys to be integers.